# Finite numbers that cannot be represented with $4m+7k$ using complete induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I need to prove that there exist finite amount of numbers that cannot be represented with $n=4m+7k~ |~ m,k \in \mathbb{N}$ .

Starting:

We say that $A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | n=4m+7k \geq 18   ~~~ m,k \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{1,2, \dots 17\}$

We say that:

$18,10,20,21 \in A$ (by hand)

And assume each number between $18 \leq m \leq n-1 | n\geq 22$ are in A.

And so:

$n-4 \geq 18$ because $n\geq22$

We know that $n-4 \in A$
So: $n-4 = 4m +7k \rightarrow  n = 4m+4+7k \rightarrow n=4(m+1)+7k$
And we proved that $n \in A$
And thus $A = \mathbb{N}$   an infinite set and $\{n \in \mathbb{N} | n=4m+7k \geq 18   ~~~ m,k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is infinite.
so: $\{1...17\}$ is finite set. QED.

I am not sure about this proof because it seems "specific" about $n-4$, and what about $n-3$?

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: It isn’t clear what’s bothering you. By the time you’re showing that $n\in A$, you already know that $n-3\in A$.

Comment: that's the so called [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But we assume n-3 is in A, because n-4 - n-1  are in A, and we need to prove that n is in A also

Comment: @Remember1312: I still don’t see what’s bothering you. We use the fact that $n-4$ is known to be in $A$ to prove that $n$ is also in $A$, and that proof is completely straightforward.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott wait so my proof is O-K ?

Comment: @Remember1312: Yes, with one small exception it’s fine. At the end you say that $\{1,\ldots,17\}$ is finite, which is true but not quite what you want. You want to conclude that there are only finitely many positive integers that cannot be represented as $4m+7k$ with $m,k\in\Bbb N$. You’ve shown that the set of such numbers is a **subset** of $\{1,\ldots,17\}$, so it’s certainly finite, but the way that you’ve phrased it suggests that the set of such numbers **is** the set $\{1,\ldots,17\}$, which is false. (E.g., $11=4\cdot1+7\cdot 1$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you Sir!

Comment: @Remember1312: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but here is a cool way that I like to teach younger children of realizing this fact. Suppose we have a number $n = 4m_1 + 7k_1$. Note that if $k_1 \geq 1$, then we can immediately conclude that $n + 1$ is expressible as $4m + 7k$, as we can "exchange" one of the sevens for two fours, thereby constructing $n + 1$. That is $n + 1 = 4(m_1 + 2) + 7(k_1 - 1)$.

With these facts, we now notice that if $n = 4m + 7k$ with $k \geq 3$, then we can construct $n + 1$, $n + 2$, and $n + 3$ just by trading in our sevens one at a time for two fours. Of course, $n + 4$ is easily constructable as it is just $4 (m + 1) + 7k$, and again we can begin the exchanging process to construct the next three natural numbers (since again $k \geq 3$ and hence $n + 4$ has $3$ sevens to "exchange"). This implies that every number after $7 \cdot 3 = 21$ is constructable, so indeed there are only finitely many natural numbers that are not of form $4m + 7k$.

Note that this little heuristic works for any two relatively prime numbers $p$ and $q$. That is, there are finitely many numbers not expressible as $mp + kq$ for such $p$ and $q$.